# import instrument track [Logic Pro X]

Tags: logic-pro

How can I import an instrument track from one project to another?

I have a project got messed up, let's call it "OLD" and I want to redo it in to a new project NEW.

I want to copy tracks from OLD into NEW. The OLD tracks I want to copy have Drum kit from hell (a software instrument).

How do I copy them?

I tried: Logic > Import > MIDI. But I did not see the file I want there.

iMac
 Logic Pro X 10.4.8
 EZ Drummer 2 + DKFH (all updated)

Comment: Did you save the tracks of the old project as midifiles?

Comment: No, I did not save the tracks of the old project as midifiles.

Comment: Are you talking about regions, the actual MIDI information? I have copied and pasted regions from one Logic project to another. You can have both projects open at the same time and go  back and forth between them.

Comment: How do you open two projects at the same time? When I choose File > Open, it gives me a dialog box for my current project: `Do you want to save the changes made to the document [...]? [Don't Save] [Cancel] [Save]`

Comment: Funny, I get a window that says Do you want to close the current project before opening a new song? Closing it is recommended unless you wish to copy data between songs. Then it has Don’t Close, Cancel, and Close. Try saving the song first then going to open in the menu.

Comment: If you search the Help menu for “open projects” open it  under “Help Topics” and all the options are explained but even if you copy something then close the project the info will still be available in the clipboard, I tested it. good luck!

Comment: To be able to open multiple projects, you have to turn on **Preferences > Advance Tools**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107018/discussion-between-john-belzaguy-and-garrett).

Answer (score 1):

You've covered the opening multiple projects thing which got you where you needed I'd expect, but a potentially more elegant way is Logic's built in 'import session data'.

You open a Logic project, go to *Logic's* browser on the right hand side (picture of camera, film and music notes). Here 'Project' allows you to browse the audio used in your project (and make various changes). However we want the other one, 'All Files', this brings up a normal file browser. If you navigate to another, existing, logic project and double click on it you bring up a list of tracks in that project.

Here you can choose to import individual tracks, and choose whether you import the whole thing or just the content, plugins, I/O settings etc. You can also import the project settings.

It's an extremely useful screen and a good one to know about!

[image: Logic's 'Import Session Data' feature]

Answer (score 0):

To be able to open multiple projects simultaneously, turn on **Preferences > Advanced Tools**.